# Using request.referer to redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two edit pages in my application. After the edits have been saved I want to redirect the user to a different page depending if they are on the '/info' page or '/edit' page. I am trying to use request.referer to find the path the user came from to decide where to redirect them.

(If they are on '/info' they came from '/users/sign_up')

**Controller**

```
if URI(request.referer).path == '/users/sign_up'
  redirect_to root_path, notice: "Welcome" 
else 
 redirect_to user_path(@user)
 end
```

The problem is it redirects to user_path regardless of where the user is.

(BTW, i'm not set on using request.referer to solve this. I have also tried using 'current_uri = request.env['PATH_INFO']' with the same luck)

Comment: `debugger` or `pry` or `puts` is your friend in this case.  check why `URI(request.referer).path == '/users/sign_up'` always fails and you should be able to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help - now realize it gives me '/info' not 'users/sign_up'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are on the /info and then perform edits, you are going to a separate action and another page (the edit page).  So the referer is going to be the info page not the page before it.  Try:

```
if URI(request.referer).path == '/info'
  redirect_to root_path, notice: "Welcome" 
else 
 redirect_to user_path(@user)
 end
```